# Proper return value for TVN_KEYDOWN

Tags: winapi, treeview, incremental-search

I have very recently answered to the question about [Creating TreeView with nodes and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441747/c-winapi-creating-treeview-with-nodes-and-checkboxes/22443388#22443388).

While I was pondering how to properly process the case when `treeview`'s node is checked when user pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> I ran into [`TVN_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification.

My solution was tested in a dialog box and in a window procedure and both seem to work flawlessly.

Still, I have a dilemma of what should be my returned result. Here is the relevant excerpt from the documentation for `TVN_KEYDOWN`:

> Return value
>
> If the wVKey member of lParam is a character key code, the character
>   will be used as part of an incremental search. Return nonzero to
>   exclude the character from the incremental search, or zero to include
>   the character in the search. For all other keys, the return value is
>   ignored.

I have tried returning both results when testing if <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pressed and haven't noticed any difference.

So I ask you the following questions:

1. Can someone explain me what is the incremental search ?
2. What is the difference when I include or exclude the tested character (<kbd>spacebar</kbd>) from incremental search ?

### EDIT:

It seems that I have found an answer to first question. I have found an article on [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search) that explains what incremental search is.

It leaves only the second question to be answered.

### END OF EDIT

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: Try without TVS_CHECKBOXES style a with one item starting with space character. Then you see difference between 0 return value and 1 return value.

Comment: @Xearinox: I have removed checkboxes as you have said, and added 2 spaces in the title of the second subitem. Still no difference in performance. After rereading the remarks section again I have seen that `wVKey` must be a character so I have changed my code to test against `0x54` which is `t` and still saw no performance difference. Can you please tell me what am I missing? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: You must add space only to one item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most visible in a giant TreeView.  The best example of one is the left panel in Regedit.exe.  Expand HKCR and start typing to see the effect.

The implementation has changed across Windows versions, it used to be a lot less usable in XP.  It is a UI blooper, there isn't any good way for the user to see that he mistyped a letter, to correct a typing mistake or to see that a search starts from scratch.  Current versions of Windows use a timeout, automatically resetting the partially typed search phrase when you don't hit a key for a couple of seconds.  Which is about as practical as it gets.  It is certainly useful, just not very usable.

The only sane thing to do with TVN_KEYDOWN is *nothing*.  Never add more ways to make it less predictable than it already is.  Intentionally swallowing a keystroke of course makes it a *lot* less usable if it is a key the user really wanted to use.  You certainly don't want to swallow a space, that's of course a valid character in tree node text.  If the tree happens to not have *any* nodes with text that contains a space then you *still* don't want to swallow it, the control itself already does.

The notification would have been a lot more useful if it also passed the incremental search string that was collected or give a way to reset it.  It just doesn't so that's water under the bridge.  Consider handling it if you've created some kind of usability trap, very hard to come up with a practical example of one.  You know it when you see it.

The only real use is to *completely* replace the search function.  You'd then make your own rules and select a node yourself.  And of course *always* return a non-zero value.

Comment: "The only real use is to completely replace the search function. You'd then make your own rules and select a node yourself. And of course always return a non-zero value."  I am using `TVN_KEYDOWN` **just to determine if node is checked or not**. I would like to keep the default behavior after I perform the check, please see the short code snippet for `WM_NOTIFY` I linked to in my post to get the better idea of what I am talking about (it is  in the first sentence ). Should I return non-zero in this case too? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I also have a similar task to implement regarding treeview control.The answer OP linked to solves this, but since I will use his solution, I will have the same dilemma about return value as he does.I would like to know which value should I return in his handling of the message to retain default behavior (OP just used this message to get trees check state when spacebar is pressed so there is no need to change anything) ?

Answer (score 2):

You want only answer to the second question, so this is:

If you exclude spacebar from incremental search, you dont find trewview item with spacebar.

Note: You must disable TVS_CHECKBOXES style, because treeview wndproc handle spacebar different with this style set.